# Uploading photos to a Fan Page Album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos, fan-page

I'm creating an Application to upload photos to an album on a Fan Page. 
This all seams to work as long as I'm the administrator for that Fan Page using the "**manage_pages**" permissions... but whenever I try to upload it as a "**regular**" user it fails because the user doesn't have the administrator rights (which of course makes perfectly sense).

I just can't seem to find a solution to solve my problem and to allow people to upload photos to the Fan Page's Album without becoming an fan-page administrator.

I really hope someone can help me since I've been struggling a few days trying to get this to work.

Cheers, Dwight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-Admins are not allowed to post to a fan page's album.  They can post a picture to the page's feed.  The page's feed album is different than the admin album.  I tested this out last week for a similar question asked on S/O.

Comment: It should be possible, because the following application seems to do this as well: https://www.facebook.com/IAmNikonNL?sk=app_100483226719162

Comment: Maybe Nikon is using a app that's on the white list that is getting special API calls not accessible to us who aren't on the white list.  The white list is real and lots of apps use it.